# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar una imagen en un JFrame dependiendo de un resultado?

Tags: java

Como lo puse en el título, quiero que en un JFrame se muestre una de tres imágenes dependiendo de un resultado en el código, siendo los resultados `Equilatero`, `Escaleno` o `Isósceles`.

Este es el código que determina el resultado y lo imprime en el JFrame que, como dije, quiero que además muestre una imagen dependiendo del resultado.

```
private void CActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
       double la,lb,lc;
       double a;
       double p;
       String t=null;

       la=Double.parseDouble(LA.getText());
       lb=Double.parseDouble(LB.getText());
       lc=Double.parseDouble(LC.getText());

      if (la==lb && la==lc){
        t=("Equilatero");
     }else if (la==lb || lb==lc || la==lc) {
        t=("Isósceles");  
     }else if (la!=lb || lb!=lc || la!=lc) {
        t=("Escaleno");    
     }
     if (lb+lc>la && la+lc>lb && la+lb>lc){
         a=Math.sqrt((la+lb+lc)*(-la+lb+lc)*(la-lb+lc)*(la+lb-lc)/16);
         p=la+lb+lc;
         //A.setText("El area del triangulo "+t+" es ("+a+").");
         A.setText("El triangulo "+t+" tiene un area de ("+a+") y un perimetro de ("+p+").");  
     } else {
         A.setText("Los valores ("+la+"), ("+lb+") y ("+lc+") no corresponden a los lados de un triangulo."); 
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más sencilla de hacerlo es añadiendo un `JLabel` al `JFrame` y asignando un `ImageIcon` a su propiedad `Icon`

```
private JLabel label;
label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(" Url de la Imagen"));
```

si lo haces de forma gráfica, arrastras y soltar controles , solo añade el `JLabel` y asignarle un nombre , para su caso sería

```
 if (la==lb && la==lc){
    t=("Equilatero");
    nombredelLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Url de la Imagen"));
 }else if (la==lb || lb==lc || la==lc) {
    t=("Isósceles"); 
    nombredelLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Url de la Imagen"));
 }else if (la!=lb || lb!=lc || la!=lc) {
    t=("Escaleno");  
    nombredelLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Url de la Imagen"));
 }
```

Comment: como debo de poner la ruta de la imagen?

Comment: `./`  para hacer referencia a la raiz de tu proyecto. desde ahí podrías direccionarte a carpetas y/o archivos, por ejemplo `./imagenes/img1.jpg`